# Splits a large pdf into multiple smaller pdf files

Tags: pdf

I have a large pdf files with almost 95000 pages. It contains 12000 statements. I need to split into individual statement. I use pdftk, but it is too slow, only generate 2 statements every 7 minutes. Do you know any good software which can be run in command line.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/):

```
cpdf -split in.pdf -o %%%.pdf
```

would generate 001.pdf, 002.pdf etc. There are other special codes to make nice output names.

You can use `-chunksize n` to split into groups of more than one page.

Since you say there are 95000 page and 12000 statements, perhaps the statements are of different lengths. In which case, you can do it manually:

```
cpdf in.pdf 3455-3471 -o out.pdf
```

to extract pages 3455-3471 to out.pdf

cpdf is free for non-commercial use. We have a support email address too.

There's also a comprehensive [manual](http://coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can trust pdfbox on this. It is very fast and reliable. It also has a command line way to split or merge pdf documents. Very handy!

Once you download the jar provided, you can simply do your job by

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar PDFSplit [OPTIONS] <PDF file>
```

Check out the link below on the options:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/#pdfSplit

You can also try some online tools. http://www.pdfPi.com is also very handy to use. The file size upload limit is 100MB.

Comment: The first link provided for the jar file does not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this java app: https://github.com/reinardhz/project-split-file

I made it myself because the "split" app too slow to split large file. You can split any file using that.